# Whether the dedicated camera module of raspberry pi 3 is a not available in Windows 10 IoT Core

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

All.

I am using a dedicated camera module for the raspberry pi 3.
The operating system is using Windows10 IoT Core.

I'd like to operate the camera module previously described by universal Windows application, but I saw an article that is not available other than the Web camera.

However, such as Windows10 IoT Core of raspberry pi 3 in one article is insider preview is, also the official version in some articles, I am confused by the variety of articles.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/hardwarecompatlist#Cameras

Dedicated camera module Will that not available from the current even Windows 10 IoT Core.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dedicated pi camera module is not supported by windows IoT core yet, see to this [post.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/46570c72-9c89-477f-b220-74bc02638618/support-for-official-raspberry-pi-camera?forum=WindowsIoT)。

But it's definitely on the way. And if you may find something useful, this is the official ms iot bsp [repository](https://github.com/ms-iot/bsp/tree/master/drivers).

So, stay tuned.

Comment: It's a year later, any update? I checked that folder but by the names couldn't tell if any related to the camera module. Thanks!